# A second operation cannot be started when using ContinueWith

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I have a loop and within the loop I'm doing:

```
await Task.Delay(1000, ct).ContinueWith(async _ =>
{
    await SecondMethodAsync(ct);
});
```

The second method gets an entity using EF, sets some properties and saves the entity back to the datastore by calling `await SaveChangesAsync()` on the `DbContext`.

The above should wait for 1s and then continue with the second method. With the above implementation I get the following exception:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

When I change the above to:

```
await Task.Delay(1000, ct);
await SecondMethodAsync(ct);
```

Everything works fine.

What is the difference with the above 2 snippets and how do I get to make the first snippet work?

Comment: How you have defined the loop? If you are using `enumerable.ForEach` then it can create the issue as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363807/a-second-operation-started-on-this-context-before-a-previous-asynchronous-operat

Comment: Just a simple `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {}`

Comment: I think your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697167/use-an-async-callback-with-task-continuewith)

Comment: As a side note, your code violates this guideline: [Do not create tasks without passing a TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008). Also are you sure that you want to call the `SecondMethodAsync` even when the `Task.Delay` has been canceled?

Comment: Issue is that EF Core do not support "simultaneous" operations on same `DbContext` instance. If you want to execute db operations "simultaneously" create different DbContext instance for every operation (use DbContextFactory)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [A Tour of Task, Part 7: Continuations](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) by the async/await guru [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary):

> In conclusion, I do not recommend using ContinueWith at all, unless you are doing dynamic task parallelism (which is extremely rare). In modern code, you should almost always use await instead of ContinueWith. There are several benefits to await.

You know the solution and it's great:

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), ct);
await SecondMethodAsync(ct);
```

Answer (score 10):

I think the reason is the following. Please correct me anybody if I am wrong.

The `async` lambda inside `ContinueWith` returns `Task`, which means the `ContinueWith` is actually done right after it gets that `Task` (not when the `Task` is completed). The program flow goes right into the next loop iteration and hitting that `DBContext` again.

So the following might also work since the return type of `ContinueWith` is `Task<Task>`:

```
await await Task.Delay(1000, ct).ContinueWith(async _ => {
    await SecondMethodAsync(ct); 
});
```

Comment: i did not know that we could use 2 await  right after each other, I tried to wrap one in () :D +